# Understanding bash brace expansion

Tags: linux, bash, expansion, brace-expansion

I read this post: https://superuser.com/questions/304807/brace-expansion-run-several-commands-instead-of-expanding-on-one-line and tried its `eval echo` way of expansion. Why are the two commands below different?

---

Command 1:

```
$ eval echo\ {a,b,c}\;
```

Result 1:

```
a
b
c
```

---

Command 2:

```
$ eval echo\ {a,b,c} \;
```

Result 2:

```
a echo b echo c
```

Answer (score 5):

The `eval` is just confusing things, so get rid of it:

```
$ echo echo\ {a,b,c}\;
echo a; echo b; echo c;
$ echo echo\ {a,b,c} \;
echo a echo b echo c ;
```

That should make it obvious what's happening.  In the first case, eval executes three different echo commands. In the second, it only evaluates one command that takes the string 'a echo b echo c' as an argument.